# Significance test for cross-entropy of 2 classifiers

Tags: statistical-significance, cross-entropy

Firstly, I have seen [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112144/significance-test-for-entropy) post and my question is different.

I have trained 2 probabilistic classifiers on a task to correctly predict one out of $O$ output labels ($O$ is around 40 labels). I then tested their performance on a test data set which contains $N$ samples.

I have a strange result where one classifier has an accuracy of 0.4 and average cross-entropy loss of $\approx 2.4$ and the other has an accuracy of 0.38 and average cross entropy loss of $\approx 1.8$.

I can run accuracy based significance test like the [McNemar Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test) but I want to run a test on the average cross-entropy loss. What is the correct way to show 1.8 is significantly better/different from $2.4$?

Comment: Why don't you use an "approximate randomization test" instead of McNemar? I believe it fits better in your scenario.

Comment: could you give a reference?

Comment: Sure, for example: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00223980.1969.10543491